# why to put [0] on the result of children (':first')?

Tags: jquery, children

Please explain the [0] in this code:

```
$(function (){      
    var $cont = $('#cont');     
    var $el = $cont.children(':first'), el = $el[0];    
});
```

I tried some 'alert' to find the text, but i don't really understand why we precise the index, while we already know that we're pointing on the "first" children of the div... ?

Comment: Isn't the difference that .children returns a jQuery object containing the first element (with all jQuery functionality on it) and [0] returns the HTML element itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the above example, `$el` is a jQuery object containing one element which is ensured by the `:first` selector. On the other hand, `el` contains the underlying DOM element of the first (and only) item in the `$el` jQuery object.

You can access native properties of the `el` variable, like `.innerHTML`. You can use all jQuery supported operations on `$el`, like `$el.html()`.

Comment: thanks! so why, i mean, what's the purpose to target the element inside a jquery object? for what kind of exemple do we need to target the javascript element? jquery handles the same as "plain" js doesn't it?

Comment: jQuery implements its own functions, completely wrapping the DOM elements, you can't use native properties on jQuery objects, like my example with `innerHTML/html()` above. You might need the original element if you pass them to javascript libraries not supporting jQuery, to work around a bug in jQuery before the fix is released, to use browser-specific functionality, or for anything else. It's always nice to have an option in libraries to unwrap and get the original object.

Answer (score 2):

A jQuery object normally contains a collection/array of DOM nodes.  For instance, if you are iterating over a jQuery object such as -

```
$('div').each(function() {

  //In this context, this refers to the DOM node
  //and $(this) refers to a jQuery object for that particular DOM node
  //therefore $(this)[0] == this

   this.innerHTML = 'foo';
   $(this).html('foo');
   $(this)[0].innerHTML = 'foo';

});
```

You can also use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) for a similar effect.

```
//retrieves an array of native DOM nodes using jQuery
var allDivNodes = $('div').get();

//retrieves the first node retrieved by the selector
var firstDiv = $('div').get(0);

//this is the same as get(0), however, using an array accessor can throw an exception
var firstDiv = $('div')[0];
```

Comment: thanks! so why, i mean, what's the purpose to target the element inside a jquery object? for what kind of exemple do we need to target the javascript element? jquery handles the same as "plain" js doesn't it?

Comment: For the most part, you don't need to.  But browsers can have slightly different implementations of the DOM and properties/methods can vary.  Sometimes it is desirable to use the native node itself.

Answer (score 1):

All jQuery queries return a list of all objects that matched. `:first` does not guarantee a single result, thus [0] grabs a single element.

Comment: thanks! well, if we target a div's id , and we put "first" on it, we're pretty sure that it will match only "one" element, the first one, no?

Comment: @Paul, depends. A simple query that uses `:first` but returns more than one element is `ul li:first`. That query returns the first `li` tag of every `ul` tag, but there can easily be more than one `ul` tag on the page (thus returning multiple results). A more obscure version of this query would be `$("ul").find("li:first")`. Same thing, but much harder to see that there are multiple results.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $el = $cont.children(':first')
```

If the selector matches, that gives you an *array-like object with the matched element*. What you want is the *matched element* - that's why you use the `[0]` - to get the first *(and only)* element of the returned "array".

This is basically like the difference between: `[element]` and `element` (Where, `[element][0] = element`)

Answer (score 1):

[0] is the same thing as using [get(0)](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to obtain the DOM element, not the jQuery element.